# First 3 characters of last word using regex?

Tags: regex

Assuming you have a string like these 2 examples:

1. ABC DEF GHI JKL MNOPQR STUVWX
2. ABC DEF GHI JKL MNOPQR STU VWX

In the first example, I want to return STU, and in the second, VWX

- I know that I can use ^.{3} to get the first 3 letters of the entire string, e.g. ABC.
- I know that I can use [A-Za-z]+$ to get the final word, e.g. STUVWX, and VWX.
- What I can't figure out is how to combine this into one regex that returns STU and VWX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a capture group to match 3 chars A-Za-z, and match optional chars until the end of the string.

To prevent a partial match, you might prepend a word boundary `\b`

```
\b([A-Za-z]{3})[A-Za-z]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RsoH5c/1)

Another option using lookarounds to get a match only could be asserting a whitespace boundary to the left, and assert optional chars A-Za-z till the end of the string to the right.

```
(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]{3}(?=[A-Za-z]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f3PidD/1)